# How to limit Mongodb Ram memory usage on Windows server?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I read in a blog(http://www.captaincodeman.com/2011/02/27/limit-mongodb-memory-use-windows/) mongodb memory usage can be restrict by windows server's feature WSRM.

But this feature is not available in windows server 2012.

Any one can guide me how to limit the mongo db memory usage in windows server 2012?

Comment: May be you will found it useful, i started to use linux to solve the same problem ,here is solution: http://www.techpaste.com/2016/04/limit-mongodb-memory-usage/